# Issue in JS library files while destroying the param query instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

i am working on param query grid. after selecting the rows from the grid, disabled the grid and by clicking modify button, i am enabling the grid again using below lines.

```
$imAppPQGrid.pqGrid("widget").pqGrid('option',{disabled:true});
$imAppPQGrid.pqGrid("widget").pqGrid('option',{disabled:false});
```

while reloading the json into grid, i have below code:

```
if($imAppPQGrid.pqGrid('instance')){
$imAppPQGrid.pqGrid('destroy');
}
```

it is destroying but not able to instantiate the object again, giving exception in JS Lib file. 
uncaught exp: instance not initialized...
if i do not use disable/enable functionality then it works fine. please suggest me what is the issue?

Comment: and how is java involved?

Comment: In the back end , we are using Java to get the JSON data but there is no issue with Java code .